# Are subtle and causal bodies inseparable?

Tags: yoga, moksha, body

There are three bodies for every living being including human: stula (physical), sushma (subtle) and causal (karana).

It is evident that physical body can be separated from reamining two. Subtle and causal bodies, afaik, generally stay together till attaining moksha. The causal body will disappear after attaining moksha .

Is there any possibility of separating causal body from subtle body before attaining moksha?

Comment: There are five bodies not three.

Comment: Sthula sukshama kariya karana mahakarana deha.

Comment: @ParabrahmanJyoti Oh thanks for information.